# Eclipse Compilation Error

Tags: eclipse, javacc

I imported some JTB and JavaCC generated files into Eclipse and there is *one* line giving me an error - the first line (a comment) most of the class files says "The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing and adding the JRE in your project?

1. Select `Project` -> `Properties`
2. Select `Java Build Path`
3. Navigate to the `Libraries` Tab
4. Remove the JRE
5. Click `Add Library` and add the default JRE again

PS: `Project` -> `Clean` can be very useful, too.

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing both of those and unfortunately it didn't get rid of the error... this is driving me nuts!

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project? - Sometimes the `.classpath` file for the Eclipse project is messed up.

Comment: Yep :( I'll try again though just in case

Comment: ya same with me it's not working